# When does Provider in Android initialized if we disable then enable it again?

Tags: android

I'm working with Provider in Android. I have a service that enables the provider when the service starts & disables the provider when the service stops. It enables/disables the provider like this

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                component,
                enable ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
                       : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

I saw many references that ["Content providers are automatically created when your process starts up"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966418/start-a-content-provider-by-default-android), but I can't find any reference saying when does the Provider is initialize if it's disable then enable again.